# Are any of the story lines optional in Days Gone?

Tags: days-gone

I'm at the beginning of Days Gone, and it has various story lines. You may complete them in any order you choose, I'm wondering if any of them are optional, or if you must complete them all to finish the game.  For example, can you skip the "Bounty Hunter" story line?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you do have to complete all of the story lines to advance the main story. I played to the point where I had only one story line open, the Bounty Hunter mission "Seeds for Spring" to capture Lynchman.  I attempted to obtain additional story lines by driving around the unexplored areas of the map, and was able to find an ambush camp and a NERO checkpoint, which gave me the story lines for those areas. However, I did eventually have to complete the Bounty Hunter mission before it would advance the main story line.

**EDIT:**

After I got further into the game, some of the story lines do become optional. There are definitely points where you must complete specific side missions before the main story advances.

Comment: I can't see how this answers your question. It is a good question, but considering that you handed in an answer to your own question, there is definetly a lot of context missing, how this is supposed to answer your question.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not saying you are wrong, I just don't see how this answers your question. So if you add some more context about WHY you think this is an answer and it turns out you are right, I am totally inclined to make my -1 a +1